# I want to call FetchData function from Constants.js page

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

**This is my code:**

```
import { SetCommonButtons} from "../../../../Utils/Constants";

const Main = () => {
const setButton = (cell, row) => {
    return SetCommonButtons(row)
  };

  const Columns = [
    {
      dataField: "status",
      text: "Action",
      editable: false,
      formatter: setButton,
    },
  ];

  const FetchData = () => {
    List(Id).then((response) => {
      
    });
  };

};
export default Main;
```

Comment: Can you please share the constant.js file as well. Also please elaborate scenario

Comment: This Main file used for userdata list. Data getting from fetchData function. So I need this function in Constant.js file. Should I repeat this function there also? Can I call this fetchData function from Constant.js file?

Comment: This is not complete code. Having mistakes. Its for getting the concept.